# Curl command in bash CGI script not displaying the XML output [data not shown]

Tags: bash, scripting, curl, cgi

if I run this command in linux shell.

```
curl=`curl --connect-timeout 4 -k -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" --data "<MyRequest><HeartBeat timestamp=\"1311157780201\"></HeartBeat></MyRequest>" http://192.168.1.100:8484/rest/service?action=heartbeat 2>&1 | tee`

echo "$curl"
```

I get following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyResponse><HeartBeat status="SUCCESS"></HeartBeat></MyResponse>
```

But when the same command is executed in a bash CGI script and output is displayed in html pre tags, I see some weird table and no XML data is displayed at all.

in CGI bash script i have this code

```
    curl=`curl --connect-timeout 4 -k -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" --data "<MyRequest><HeartBeat timestamp=\"1311157780201\"></HeartBeat></MyRequest>" http://192.168.1.100:8484/rest/service?action=heartbeat 2>&1 | tee`

echo "<h2> RAW Troubleshooting Data </h2><pre>"
echo "$curl"
echo "</pre>"
exit 0
```

instead of XML data, following table is displayed in the web browser.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  

Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0    76      0    424 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   424
202   126    0   126    0    76    302    182 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   210
```

However, if I use the curl verbosity with -v command in cgi bash script I get following out in my web browser but still the XML response is missing.

```
* About to connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx port xxxxx (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx... connected
* Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxxxx (#0)
> POST /rest/service?action=heartbeat HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 76
> 
} [data not shown]
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0    76      0    422 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   422< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2019 18:53:44 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.32
< 
{ [data not shown]

202   126    0   126    0    76    284    171 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   190
202   126    0   126    0    76    284    171 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   190* Connection #0 to host xx.xxx.xxx.xx left intact

* Closing connection #0
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you see is curl’s informational output about what it’s doing. It goes to STDERR. You are redirecting STDERR to STDOUT (`2>&1`), so that’s why you are seeing it.

You need to either remove that redirect or silence curl output by adding `--silent`. As for why you don’t get the output you want, that’s not entirely clear but the `| tee` at the end looks superfluous and is missing a target file name so won’t be helping matters.

Comment: ok, If I remove (2>&1) and remove pipe tee command, also tried using -s or --silent argument, but then page becomes completely blank, no output is displayed at all.

Comment: That is odd. What happens if you add `--output /tmp/something` and you do `cat /tmp/something` instead of the `echo`? Is that still blank?

Comment: It is the stupid browser that is not displaying the result. Everything always worked, I can see the XML data in the file, but when echo in pre tags within html it is not displayed by the browser. Thanks for your help